# Apply Matrix Transformations to BoundingBox

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, collision-detection, libgdx

I have a model matrix that I am keeping track of for position of the mesh in my world. With each call to `glRotate()` and `glTranslate()` I have a corresponding call to `modelMatrix.rotate()` and `modelMatrix.translate()` which appears to be working correctly.

Now I need to update the bounding box associated with each of my models. I'm working in the libGDX framework and in the `BoundingBox` class [found here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/collision/BoundingBox.html), there is a method `mul()` that should allow me to apply a matrix to the bounding box but the values are not being updated correctly and I think it may be the way I am trying to apply it. Any ideas?

Here is my relevant code:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();

// Set the model matrix to the identity matrix
modelMatrix.idt();

// Update the orbit value of this model
orbit = (orbit + ORBIT_SPEED * delta) % 360;
gl.glRotatef(orbit, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0);

// Update the model matrix rotation
modelMatrix.rotate(1.0f, 1.0f, 0, orbit);

// Move the model to it's specified radius
gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -ORBIT_DISTANCE);

// Update the model matrix translation
modelMatrix.translate(0, 0, -ORBIT_DISTANCE);

// Update the bounding box
boundingBox.mul(modelMatrix);

if (GameState.DEBUG)
{
    renderBoundingBox(gl, delta);
}

// Bind the texture and draw
texture.bind();
mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);

gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Just to be sure, are you loading an identity before  drawing your bounding box?

Comment: No, I don't have any calls to `glLoadIdentity()` until after I draw the models and bounding box.

Comment: I think you should. Because you are transforming your bb 2 times. do a push / pop inside the renderbb. keep the projection. If you want todo test the transforms dont load the identity and dont call mul(). That way you'd be drawing te bb with the same transforms as te model. Should work.

Comment: Why make the same calculations twice, using two different libraries? Maybe they make different assumptions (e.g. one may rotate clockwise, while the other rotates counter clockwise). Just calculate these matrix manipulations once on your modelMatrix, and use glLoadMatrix().

Answer (score 0):

The order that matrix multiplication is computed is important. Can you do ModelMatrix * Box instead. I think that's the issue.